# Why XCode changes images in xcassets folder while packing?

Tags: ios, xcode

I optimized and put compressed images into Images.xcassets

When I build the package and look into the contents of it, I see that all of the images are modified by XCode (build tools etc..) and for example `Default-568h@2x.png` (218KB) becomes  `LaunchImage-568h@2x.png`(455KB)

This makes it impossible for me to put optimized images.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is most likely premultiplied alpha channel. I ran into this same issue when designing my game engine and it was relatively painless to fix.

Last I knew there is no option to disable premultiplied alpha channels for the Xcode bundle.However, Xcode comes bundled with a textureool which can be used at build time to format your images into another format that does not suffer this same optimization. Since my code focuses on sending texture data to OpenGL i used the powerVR format PVRTC. However, you're free to utilizes whatever format you like.

If you decide to go this route you can add a build target to your project which converts all png files into which ever format you prefer.